# Why is this image contained in the kernel

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $u: X \to X$ be compact and $\lambda$ a non zero complex number. Let $W=X/(u-\lambda)(X)$. Let $\pi : X \to W$ be the quotient map. If $X^\ast$ denotes the dual I assume that $\pi^\ast$ denotes the quotient map

$$ \pi^\ast : X^\ast \to X^\ast / (u^\ast-\lambda)(X^\ast)$$

Could someone please help me understand why $\mathrm{im}(\pi^\ast)\subseteq \mathrm{ker}(u^\ast - \lambda)$? It should be "obvious" but it's not obvious to me. What is obvious to me is that $\mathrm{im}(u^\ast -\lambda) \subseteq \ker{\pi^\ast}$. Maybe I am misunderstanding what the map $\pi^\ast$? This is all mentioned on page 22 in Murphy's book.

**Edit** The following is an image of the relevant page:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you give a more precise reference, like the title of Murphy's book? Or better still, give a link to a scanned image of said page? Otherwise, I suppose that $\pi^*$ should mean the dual map $\pi^* : W^* \to X^*$ defined by $\pi^*(v) = v\circ\pi$ for $v \in X^*$. Since $\pi$ is a quotient map, $\pi^*$ thus defined will be an injection, not another quotient map.

Comment: If my assumption is correct, then proving the inclusion $\operatorname{im}(\pi^*) \subseteq \operatorname{ker}(u^*-\lambda)$ amounts to showing that $(u^*-\lambda)\circ\pi^* = (\pi\circ(u-\lambda))^*$ is the zero map $W^* \to X^*$, which is a tautology.

Comment: @ivanpenev Thank you for your comments, I added an image of the relevant page. Reading your first comment your suggestion for $\pi^\ast$ seems plausible.

Comment: The definition of $\pi^*$ is made clear in the formula $\sigma = \tau\circ \pi = \pi^*(\tau)$ on the fifth line from the bottom.

Comment: @ivanpenev Thank you for your helpful comments, I understand it now. Please can I ask you one more question about this proof? Where it says that $\sigma$ induces a bounded linear functional $\tau$ is that because of the universal property of quotient maps?

Comment: You're welcome. The answer to your question is 'yes'.

Comment: @ivanpenev Thank you for your comment but I am sorry I don't get it. I've been trying to make the diagram work. Can you help me please?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to draw a nice commutative diagram on this site. But I suppose that neither the problem nor the solution is in the diagram. To make sure that we are on the same page, let's recall that by definition, for any $w \in W$ we have   $\tau(w) = \sigma(x)$ where $x$ is an arbitrary element of $X$ such that $\pi(x) = w$. (to be continued)

Comment: To show that $\tau$ is bounded, observe that for any such $x$, we have $$|\tau(w)| = |\sigma(x)| \leq ||\sigma||\cdot||x||.$$ Since $x$ is an arbitrary element of the coset $\pi^{-1}(w)$, we deduce that $$|\tau(w)|\leq||\sigma||\inf_{x \in\pi^{-1}(w)}||x||=||\sigma||\cdot||w||,$$ by the definition of the norm on $W$. This shows that $\tau$ is bounded, with norm less than or equal to $||\sigma||$.

Comment: @ivanpenev Thank you for your help! It looks as if this doesn't have anything to do with the universal property of quotient vector spaces. You define $\tau$ in terms of $\sigma$. My idea was that by the universal property there exists a unique $\tau$ such that $\sigma = \tau \circ \pi$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14842/discussion-between-ivanpenev-and-student).

Comment: I apologise for having tried to move this discussion to chat. I was advised to do so by the system, but at least in my browser, the LaTeX expressions are not displayed correctly (or rather left unprocessed at all) in the so called 'chat room'.

Comment: @ivanpenev No problem at all. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is not correct. The notation $\pi^*$ is standard and refers to the dual map
$\pi^*:W^*\to X^*$ given by $\pi^*(f)=f\circ \pi$.

Now $\sigma$ is a bounded functional on $X$. Because it is zero on the subspace $(u-\lambda)X=\ker\pi$, one can define $\tau(\pi(x)):=\sigma(x) $. This is well-defined: if $\pi(x)=\pi(y) $, then $x-y\in\ker\pi$, so $\sigma(x-y)=0$ and $\sigma(x)=\sigma(y) $. Finally,  $\tau$ is bounded because, for any $v\in\ker\pi$,
$$
|\tau(\pi(x))|=|\sigma(x+v)|\leq\|\sigma\|\,\|x+v\|,
$$ 
so $$
|\tau(\pi(x))|=\leq\|\sigma\|\,\inf\{\|x+v\|:\ v\in\ker\pi\}=\|\sigma\|\,\|\pi(x)\|.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer! Can I ask one other thing about this proof please? There where it says that $\sigma$ "induces" a bounded linear functional $\tau$ -- is that because of the universal property of quotient maps?

Comment: I explained that in the new edit.

Comment: Thank you. So this has nothing to do with the universal property of vector quotient spaces?

Comment: Maybe it *is* appealing to the universal property. But then you wouldn't have to prove that $\tau$ is bounded and you wouldn't have to define it either because the universal property gives you the existence of a unique continuous linear map $\tau$ such that $\sigma = \tau \circ \pi$.

Comment: I'm replying to this thread because it is shorter than the one under the original question, and in order not to force @Student to ask the same question twice anymore. What Martin Argerami and I did was *proving* the following universal property: 'If $\pi : X \to W$ is a quotient map between two Banach spaces $X$ and $W$, then for any $\sigma \in X^*$ such that $\sigma(\ker \pi) = 0$, there exists a unique $\tau \in W^*$ such that $\tau \circ \pi = \sigma$. At least my impression was that you (Student) wanted to see (an idea of) a proof of that universal property.

Comment: To be more precise, neither of us commented on the uniqueness of $\tau$ or on its linearity. (Martin also showed that $\tau$ is correctly defined as a map of sets.)

Comment: @ivanpenev Thank you very much for your comments. I understand it now fully. Thank you!

Comment: @Student You're welcome.